# Get class from generic in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In my Kotlin project, I have the following class:

```
class NewTest {
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var activityTestRule: ActivityTestRule<NewActivity> =
        ActivityTestRule(NewActivity::class.java, false, false)
    .....
}
```

as the activity `rule` will be used in most of my test, I decided to write something like:

```
class BaseTestClass<T> {
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var activityTestRule: ActivityTestRule<T> =
        ActivityTestRule(T::class.java, false, false)
    .....
}
```

but this is not working. Any idea is it possible at all?

Comment: Check docs on `reified`, might be useful for you

Comment: What is the error?